# How to configure destination in HANA Cloud Platform?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

In hana cloud platform , there is a `"New project from sample application"` (I think it is recently added ? ), I created a "Approve Purchase Orders", but when I run it, there is a 500 error:

Produced by

> "requestUri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/SEPMRA_PO_APV/$metadata"

How to config `RefAppsBackend` data source in destionation?

When I new project from template, there is a place to config data connection , but why the sample application didn't provide it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create from sample application, it copies the data connection configuration of that app. Hence it doesn't provide the choice to config.

If you have already configured a backend system  for your WebIDE -> Replace `RefAppsBackend` in file `neo-app.json` with your backend system

If you don’t have a backend system configured for your `WebIDE`: Start the SAP HANA Cloud Platform.

Then open the WebIDE and choose Tools -> SAP HANA Cloud Platform Cockpit. 
In this Cockpit select ‘Destinations’ on the left side and then ‘New Destination’

Comment: I understand, But the demo app need `RefAppsBackend ` destination, how to config it ? Is there any tutorial (I didn't find it in SAPUI5 toolkit)?  Thanks.

Comment: I have updated answer.. You can change settings in `neo-app.json` and `Component.js` of your app.

Comment: so... there is no such `RefAppsBackend ` ....?  I've already change my destionation to `ES4`(https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/ ), thanks.

Comment: Above description is correct.
`RefAppsBackend` is just a placeholder, which needs to be replaced by the actual destination.
Usually the sample applications should also work with mockdata.
But it might be, that an SAP internal backend is required here.
Tina, if you are SAP employee, please search in internal SAP Portal for "Fiori Reference Applications".
You will find an internal Wiki-Page "Fiori Reference Applications Home" and info, how to get in contact with us.